# **Updated** Ethminer - no such file or Directory error after building cpp-ethereum on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: cpp-ethereum, ubuntu, ethminer

I am new to all of this, although I do some programming on Windows and the web.

I have a small rig I want to use for mining ethereum. It is a dell inspiron 560.

It has a new Nvidia GE-Force 610 video card, with driver. (2 gigs memory)

I reinstalled ubunutu 14.04 LTS, then I went here to https://github.com/Genoil/cpp-ethereum to follow the directions for a cuda miner.

I followed the directions completely and got errors during the build.

Can someone please help me to get a clean build? D I need a different version of CMake or C++?

Can someone help me run down the issues please?

Here is the report from the build/make process: (I know it is a long read. Thanks for reading it).

```
markm@Goose1:~/cpp-ethereum$ mkdir build
markm@Goose1:~/cpp-ethereum$ cd build
markm@Goose1:~/cpp-ethereum/build$ cmake -DBUNDLE=cudaminer ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- ctest path: /usr/bin/ctest
-- Found CryptoPP: /usr/include (found suitable version "5.6.2", minimum required is "5.6.2")
 - CryptoPP header: /usr/include
 - CryptoPP lib   : /usr/lib/libcryptopp.so
-- Found leveldb: /usr/include
 - LevelDB header: /usr/include
 - LevelDB lib: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libleveldb.so
-- Found jsoncpp: /usr/include/jsoncpp
 - Jsoncpp header: /usr/include/jsoncpp
 - Jsoncpp lib   : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so
-- Found json_rpc_cpp: /usr/include (found suitable version "0.4.2", minimum required is "0.4")
 - json-rpc-cpp header: /usr/include
 - json-rpc-cpp lib   : /usr/lib/libjsonrpccpp-common.so;/usr/lib/libjsonrpccpp-server.so;/usr/lib/libjsonrpccpp-client.so
-- Found mhd: /usr/include
 - microhttpd header: /usr/include
 - microhttpd lib   : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so
 - microhttpd dll   :
-- Found readline: /usr/include
 - readline header: /usr/include
 - readline lib   : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so
-- Could NOT find miniupnpc (missing:  MINIUPNPC_INCLUDE_DIR MINIUPNPC_LIBRARY)
-- Found gmp: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 - gmp header: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 - gmp lib   : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so
-- Found CURL: /usr/include
 - curl header: /usr/include
 - curl lib   : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so
-- Could NOT find cpuid (missing:  CPUID_INCLUDE_DIR CPUID_LIBRARY)
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_0
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_0 - not found
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_1_2
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_1_2 - found
-- Found OpenCL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so (found version "1.2")
 - opencl header: /usr/include
 - opencl lib   : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so
-- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda (found version "8.0")
 - CUDA header: /usr/local/cuda/include
 - CUDA lib   : /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so
 - jsonrpcstub location    : /usr/bin/jsonrpcstub
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   date_time
--   system
--   regex
--   chrono
--   filesystem
--   unit_test_framework
--   program_options
--   random
 - boost header: /usr/include
 - boost lib   : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_random.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                  CMake Version                            3.2.2
-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Build type                               Release
-- TARGET_PLATFORM  Target platform                          Linux
-- BUNDLE           Build bundle                             cudaminer
--------------------------------------------------------------- features
--                  Chromium support                         1
--                  Hardware identification support          FALSE
--                  HTTP Request support                     TRUE
-- VMTRACE          VM execution tracing                     OFF
-- PROFILING        Profiling support                        OFF
-- FATDB            Full database exploring
-- JSONRPC          JSON-RPC support                         ON
-- OLYMPIC          Default to the Olympic network           OFF
------------------------------------------------------------- components
-- MINER            Build miner                              ON
-- GUI              Build GUI components                     OFF
-- ETHASHCL         Build OpenCL components                  ON
-- ETHASHCUDA       Build CUDA components                    ON
-- ETHSTRATUM       Build Stratum components                 ON
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- CXXFLAGS: -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wextra -Wno-error=parentheses -pedantic -DSHAREDLIB -fPIC  -fuse-ld=gold creating build info... createBuildInfo()
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Configuring done CMake Warning at libethcore/CMakeLists.txt:21 (add_library):   Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target
ethcore because files   in some directories may conflict with
libraries in implicit directories:
        runtime library [libOpenCL.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/cuda/lib64
            Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.

CMake Warning at ethminer/CMakeLists.txt:22 (add_executable):   Cannot
generate a safe runtime search path for target ethminer because
files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
directories:
        runtime library [libOpenCL.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/cuda/lib64
            Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.

-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/markm/cpp-ethereum/build markm@Goose1:~/cpp-ethereum/build$ make -j2 Scanning dependencies of
target BuildInfo.h Scanning dependencie
s of target devcore Files
"/home/markm/cpp-ethereum/build/BuildInfo.h.tmp" to
"/home/markm/cpp-ethereum/build/BuildInfo.h" are different. [  2%] [
2%] Built target BuildInfo.h Building CXX object
libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/CommonData.cpp.o Scanning
dependencies of target ethash [  4%] Building C object
libethash/CMakeFiles/ethash.dir/io.c.o [  7%] Building C object
libethash/CMakeFiles/ethash.dir/internal.c.o            [  9%]
Building C object libethash/CMakeFiles/ethash.dir/io_posix.c.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object
libethash/CMakeFiles/ethash.dir/sha3_cryptopp.cpp.o   Linking CXX
shared library libethash.so [ 11%] Built target ethash Scanning
dependencies of target ethstratum [ 14%] Building CXX object
libstratum/CMakeFiles/ethstratum.dir/EthStratumClientV2.cpp.o
/home/markm/cpp-ethereum/libstratum/EthStratumClientV2.cpp: In member
function ‘void EthStratumClientV2::processReponse(Json::Value&)’:
/home/markm/cpp-ethereum/libstratum/EthStratumClientV2.cpp:350:12:
warning: variable ‘headerHash’ set but not used
[-Wunused-but-set-variable]
       h256 headerHash = h256(sHeaderHash);
            ^ [ 16%] Building CXX object libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/FixedHash.cpp.o [ 19%] Building CXX
object libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/CommonIO.cpp.o      [ 21%]
Building CXX object
libstratum/CMakeFiles/ethstratum.dir/EthStratumClient.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object
libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/SHA3.cpp.o
/home/markm/cpp-ethereum/libstratum/EthStratumClient.cpp: In member
function ‘void EthStratumClient::processReponse(Json::Value&)’:
/home/markm/cpp-ethereum/libstratum/EthStratumClient.cpp:398:12:
warning: variable ‘headerHash’ set but not used
[-Wunused-but-set-variable]
       h256 headerHash = h256(sHeaderHash);
            ^ [ 26%] Building CXX object libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/TrieCommon.cpp.o Linking CXX shared
library libethstratum.so [ 26%] Built target ethstratum [ 28%]
Generating OpenCL Kernel Byte Array [ 30%] Building CXX object
libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/Struc
turedLogger.cpp.o
Scanning dependencies of target ethash-cl [ 33%] Building CXX object
libethash-cl/CMakeFiles/ethash-cl.dir/ethash_cl_miner.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library libethash-cl.so [ 33%] Built target
ethash-cl [ 35%] Building CXX object
libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/Hash.cpp.o [ 38%] Building CXX
object libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/RangeMask.cpp.o     [ 40%]
Building CXX object libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/MemoryDB.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object
libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/Base64.cpp.o        [ 45%] Building
NVCC (Device) object
libethash-cuda/CMakeFiles/ethash-cuda.dir/ethash-cuda_generated_ethash_cuda_miner_kernel.cu.o
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures
are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use
-Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning). nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and
may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to
suppress warning).
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h(432): error:
identifier "nullptr" is undefined
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h(432): error:
expected a ";"
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h(190): error:
expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(63): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(68): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(76): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(83): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(93): error: expected a "{"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(64): error: function
"std::current_exception" returns incomplete type
"std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(64): error: expected a "{"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(79): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(81): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(82): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(84): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(86): error: declaration is
incompatible with previous "std::current_exception" (64): here
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(86): error: use of a local
type to declare a function
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(86): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(87): error: use of a local
type to declare a function
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(90): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(92): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(95): error: incomplete type
is not allowed
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(95): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(116): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(126): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(143): error: use of a local
type to declare a function
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(144): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(147): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(152): error: use of a local
type to declare a function
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(153): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(156): error: use of a local
type to declare a function
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(157): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(160): error: use of a local
type to declare a function
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(161): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(169): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/nested_exception.h(57): error: incomplete
type is not allowed
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/nested_exception.h(60): error: expected a
";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/nested_exception.h(66): error: expected a
";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/nested_exception.h(70): error: identifier
"rethrow_exception" is undefined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/nested_exception.h(73): error: function
"std::nested_exception::nested_ptr" returns incomplete type
"std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/new(95): error: expected a "{"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/new(110): error: identifier "__p" is undefined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/new(111): error: expected a "{"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/new(115): error: expected a "{"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/new(116): error: expected a "{"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/cpp_type_traits.h(184): error: identifier
"char16_t" is undefined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/cpp_type_traits.h(191): error: identifier
"char32_t" is undefined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/cpp_type_traits.h(191): error: class
"std::__is_integer<<error-type>>" has already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/cpp_type_traits.h(314): error: namespace
"std::__gnu_cxx" has no member "__normal_iterator"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/cpp_type_traits.h(314): error: expected a
">"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(80): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(80): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(105): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(105): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(105): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(124): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(124): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(124): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(143): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(143): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(143): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(162): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(162): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(162): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(183): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(183): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(183): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(202): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(202): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(202): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(221): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(221): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(221): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(240): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(240): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(240): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(259): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(259): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(259): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(278): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(278): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(278): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(297): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(297): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(297): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(328): error: "constexpr" is not a function
or static data member
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(337): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(337): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(337): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(356): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(356): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(356): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(375): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(375): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(375): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(406): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(406): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(406): error: expected a ";"
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(443): error: inline specifier allowed on
function declarations only
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(443): error: variable "std::constexpr" has
already been defined
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(443): error: expected a ";"
    Error limit reached. 100 errors detected in the compilation of
"/tmp/tmpxft_00007c86_00000000-17_ethash_cuda_miner_kernel.compute_61.cpp1.ii".
Compilation terminated. CMake Error at
ethash-cuda_generated_ethash_cuda_miner_kernel.cu.o.cmake:264
(message):   Error generating file
/home/markm/cpp-ethereum/build/libethash-cuda/CMakeFiles/ethash-cuda.dir//./ethash-cuda_generated_ethash_cuda_miner_kernel.cu.o

make[2]: ***
[libethash-cuda/CMakeFiles/ethash-cuda.dir/ethash-cuda_generated_ethash_cuda_miner_kernel.cu.o]
Error 1 make[1]: *** [libethash-cuda/CMakeFiles/ethash-cuda.dir/all]
Error 2 make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... [ 47%] Building
CXX object libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/TrieDB.cpp.o [ 50%]
Building CXX object libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/RLP.cpp.o [ 52%]
Building CXX object libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/Guards.cpp.o [
54%] Building CXX object
libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/TransientDirectory.cpp.o [ 57%]
Building CXX object libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/FileSystem.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/Log.cpp.o
[ 61%] Building CXX object
libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/Common.cpp.o [ 64%] Building CXX
object libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/CommonJS.cpp.o [ 66%]
Building CXX object libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/Worker.cpp.o [
69%] Building CXX object
libdevcore/CMakeFiles/devcore.dir/TrieHash.cpp.o Linking CXX shared
library libdevcore.so [ 69%] Built target devcore make: *** [all]
Error 2 markm@Goose1:~/cpp-ethereum/build$ cd ethminer
markm@Goose1:~/cpp-ethereum/build/ethminer$ ethminer -U -M ethminer:
command not found
```

Any and all help to get this right would be greatfully appreciated.

Comment: I think to use cuda you have to use a variant of Ethminer

Comment: Okay Thanks. Right now it is built just for the miner, but even though I can see the actual program in the folder, it does not run. Could it be a pathing issue? Does it need to be added to a path?

Comment: If I don't get it I will rebuild the box and try again.

Comment: getting the same error. Any luck?

Comment: No. I actually gave up after about 2 weeks of trying.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue as described above.
Finding that this post is 7 months old, i need to ask... has a fix been found yet? thanks

Comment: Not that I am aware of. If you find one please let me know.

Comment: In the absence of any other precise answers, I'll award the bounty to an answer that just broadly explains approaches to checking through dependencies and work through debugging - or just explains how CUDA works. I don't think the present answer contributes anything.

Answer (score 1):

Genoil's ethminer works with CUDA if your nVidia card doesn't support OpenCL or if you want maximum performance out of it.

https://github.com/Genoil/cpp-ethereum

Comment: Did you read the question? Thats the miner he is trying to compile. He even provided the same link in his question.